# unable to get .datepicker() function to initiate on dynamically loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm still quite new to JS and am having some issues with getting JS to run on a dynamically loaded page.

After loading the "Apply Online" page dynamically through the .load method I am unable to then get a jquery date picker to attach to the "appDataOfBirth" input field. After reading through a couple similar posts I've tried things such as .live however even though this works for say an alert, it won't initialize the date picker.

I've been playing around with something link below, where "applyOnlineBtn" is the carasel link to open up the application section displaying the form - however this does not seem to work.

```
$('#applyOnlineBtn').live("click", function(){
alert('test message');
$("#appDateOfBirth").datepicker();
});
```

If any one could help me to get this working it would be greatly appreciated.

Resources:
Website URL: http://www.kingsroad.net.au/qutproject/index.php

the JS that loads the content into the mid div is located at kingsroad.net.au/qutproject/js/general.js   (this is where I've attempted to use my code to activate the date picker).

the online application content is located at kingsroad.net.au/qutproject/content/applyOnline.php

Comment: i check your link, http://kingsroad.net.au/qutproject/content/applyOnline.php , date picker is loading fine in Chrome but not in Firefox and IE, seems some browser issue, are you getting same?

Comment: I think that's the default HTML5 date picker that it not yet built into Firefox/IE that's appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You May use

```
$('your_element').load(URL_TO_LOAD,function(){
  $("#appDateOfBirth").datepicker();
});
```

this will apply datepicker to the new loaded content.

Comment: Hi Shailesh Jangir,

I've added the suggested code to my .load function however it seems that the page starts looping, I've used a "if(pagename==applyOnline){$("#appDateOfBirth").datepicker(); however this seems to put the site in a loop and will not finish loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check javascript error console?:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker
```

So, check your datepicker library, maybe you've not include datepicker library in your page.